# How can I strip the link but not the text inside

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have this:

`<h1>This <i>is</i> a <a href="#someID">good</a> link</h1>`

And I want to strip out ONLY the `<a>` but not what is IN the `<a>`, and NOT the italic, so I get:

`This <i>is</i> a good link`

How can I do that in XSLT 2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
<xsl:template match="a">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

for the `a` element, together with the identity transformation template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```